# Geting access to a partition over the network

Tags: linux, disk-encryption

I want to access my user-partition from a client, so that it can encrypt the saved data without the server knowing the key, therefore the client doesn't have to trust it.
Diagram:

```
Layer5: Filesystem |   btrfs   |              Client
Layer4: Encryption |   LUKS    |              Client
Layer3: Transport        ?
Layer2: Partitions | user-part |server-part|  Server
Layer1: RAID       |   mdadm RAID5 6TB     |  Server
Layer0: HW:        |  3TB  |  3TB  |  3TB  |  Server
```

But I don't know how to access the partition. I tried NBD, but any documentation of it is outdated, so I can't get it working.
Are there alternatives to NBD?

Comment: Perhaps you should post a question with your nbd problems, as it is usually well supported.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is [iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI), which implements block-level access by transporting SCSI command over the network. In your diagram it would "fake" layer 0. All encryption/decryption will happen on the client.

See e.g. [this](https://wiki.debian.org/SAN/iSCSI/open-iscsi) for a Debian tutorial, or google for whatever distro you use.